# Property 'props' does not exist on type IntrinsicAttributes & string[]

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

Im not sure why im getting the error:

```
TypeScript error in /home/amanuel2/tutorial/go/react-go/src/frontend/src/App.tsx(34,15):
Type '{ props: string[]; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & string[]'.
  Property 'props' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & string[]'.  TS2322
```

Code:

```
function App() {

  const [ChatHistory, setChatHistory] = useState<string[]>([])
  useEffect(() => {
    connect((msg: string) => {
      console.log("New Message")
      setChatHistory([...ChatHistory, msg])
    })
    console.log(ChatHistory)
    return () => { }
  }, [])

  
  
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Header />
      <header className="App-header">
        <Chat props={ ChatHistory }/>
        <button type="submit" onClick={()=>sendMsg("Hello")}>
          Hello
        </button>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}
```

And

```
const Chat = (props: string[]) => {
  const msgs = props.map((msg:any, idx:any) => (
    <p key={ idx }>
      { msg }   
    </p>
  ))
  return (
    <div className="ChatHistory">
      <h3> Chat History </h3>
      { msgs }
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your line `<Chat props={ ChatHistory }/>` passes the type `{ props: string[] }` as the first argument (the one called `props`) into the `Chat` component, but `Chat` expects it to be `string[]`, (from `const Chat = (props: string[]) => {`).

Instead, you can change the expected type of the props of Chat:

```js
const Chat = (props: {props: string[]})
```

Now, this is not good style, since the name `props` should only be used to specify all attributes in that object.
So, instead you can rename the `ChatHistory` prop that is being passed to Chat:

```js
render() {
  // ...
  <Chat chatHistory={ChatHistory}/>
}

// ...
const Chat = (props: {chatHistory: string[]}) {
  props.chatHistory.map(  // ...
}
```